# How to use Katalon Recorder with parameters

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

There seem to not be any good documentations on this, how do you use the csv imported in `Data Driven` tab to run tests multiple times with each row? (I am able to import csv files).

I am using Katalon Recorder and not getting anything even after imported csv.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example use case.
I have a simple csv file

```
user1    | pass1
---------+------
user2    | pass2
```

in my `/Data Files` folder.

Next, you need to go to `Data Files > New > Test Data` and set `Data Type` to csv. (You probably know how to do this, but I'm writing it anyway, for completeness sake.)

Then, this simple script

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory as TestDataFactory

def data = TestDataFactory.findTestData("test (1)")

println data.getValue(1,1)
println data.getValue(2,1)
```

will print `user1` and `pass1` to console.

If I wanted to, let us say, login two times, I could do

```
for (def i=1; i <= findTestData("test (1)").getRowNumbers(); i++){
      WebUI.sendKeys('username-test-object-id', findTestData("test (1)").getValue(1, i))
      WebUI.sendKeys('password-test-object-id', findTestData("test (1)").getValue(2, i))
      WebUI.comment("User ${i} succesfully logged in!")
}
```

With an additional import:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
```

Comment: I am using Katalon Recorder.

Comment: Now you're telling me, monsieur!